# Pre-define a specific range to record cell data changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script is working cool for me.. Rather than filtering the changelog sheet to get my data I want the script to only record the changes in  a specific range lets say 'A2:E150'. With my minimal knowledge in coding I tried inserting the .getrange() thing at few places but to no luck..

So hoping someone can help me out on where to define the range exactly in the script

Code:

```
 function onEdit() {
 var sheetsToWatch = ['outcome overview', 'Sheet1', 'Another sheet'];
 // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
 var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

 var timestamp = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A2:A');
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var sheetName = sheet.getName();
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var email2 = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

 // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
 if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

 // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
 var matchFound = false;
 for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
 if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
}
 if (!matchFound) return;

 var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 1 */ 1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
 var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue();

 var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
 if (!changelogSheet) {
// no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
// Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
// ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered","email", "email2"]);
changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
}
 changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue(), email, email2]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to record changes within a given range by testing if the "ActiveCell" (`sheet.getActiveCell()`) is within a specified range.

To test if the `ActiveCell` is in a given `Range`, I would do something like this:

```
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
// .getColumn returns an integer, where A=1, B=2, etc.
if (cell.getColumn() < 6 && cell.getRow() > 1 && cell.getRow() < 151) {
    //execute script
} else {
    return
}
```

I would also recommend removing `.getRange('A2:A')` from the declaration of your variable `ss`.

Comment: Thnks a lot... tht pretty much solved my problem... :)